# Add/Remove Input Fields Dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to add and remove duplicate input fields using Jquery-

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control"></div>   

        // **** Here I want to add div using Jquery **** //

        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-info">Add More Subcategory</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
var wrapper         = $(".input_wrap"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 

$(add_button).click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  $(wrapper).prepend('<div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
});
```

When I using this Jquery its always add `div` below the `.input_wrap` DIV. But I want to add `DIV` to the place I have shown in my HTML Code.

**UPDATE:** This is the way I want to get 
[image]
Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `after` key

```
var wrapper = $(".input_wrap>div");
var add_button = $(".add_field_button");

$(add_button).click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(wrapper).after('<div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsqtesjz/)

**Edit**

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/024ovydd/1/)

Updated the fiddle to also include the remove functionallity

**Created a new Fiddle** 
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4jjtdnmL/1/)

I made a couple of small changes , the most important one is the

```
var el = $('.input_wrap div:last');
```

so that will basically get the last added div and then we will add the new div right after it.

```
$(el).after(newAdd);
```

Comment: R4nc1d, One more question. When I using this code its always inserting `DIV` below the `.input_wrap>div`. But I want to insert `DIV`s below the `input_wrap>div` and always above the button. Eg. `DIV-1, DIV-2, Div-3..` etc. But now its inserting `DIV-1, DIV-4, DIV-3, DIV-2...... ` etc. Sorry I couldn't mentioned it in my question.

Comment: You should be able to use the sorting function, to achieve the above. You can look at the following http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/C2heg/. Let me know if you don't come right

Comment: R4nc1d, sorting is not the way I need. Actually I want to add `INPUT` one after one when the button is click on.

Comment: Updated my question with an image. check it. Thank you.

Comment: ah ok, cool ill try and see if i can update my fiddle shortly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75814/discussion-between-r4nc1d-and-user3733831).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="input_wrap">
        <div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control"></div>   

        <div class="more-data"></div> 

        <button class="add_field_button btn btn-info">Add More Subcategory</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your js

```
var wrapper         = $(".input_wrap"); 
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 
var moredata      = $(".more-data"); 

$(add_button).click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault();
  moredata.html('<div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
});
```

Comment: Can I get a solution without additional markup? Thank you.

Comment: May i ask why more some wrapper div is a concern for you?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var wrapper         = $(".input_wrap");
```

to

```
var wrapper         = $(".input_wrap>div");
```

and change `prepend` to `append` to append in the existing div or `after` to place it after the existing div.

And I hope it should do, what you want.

Comment: This will append inside the available div element and hence will not work

Answer (score 1):

check the below jquery code

var add_button      = $(".add_field_button");

```
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
          e.preventDefault();
          $(".input_wrap div:last").append('<div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `insertAfter` it require the `selector` after which you want to `insert`

```
var newElement='<div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>';
$(newElement).insertAfter(".form-control");
```

but you need to give another class name to newly created input.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c5ce4fsk/)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('<div><input type="text" name="text[]" class="form-control">
<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>    
</div>').insertAfter($(wrapper).find("div")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

The best example that I've found is the below as seen in OP by Kevin Bowersox.

> [Dynamically add and remove <input> jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397259/dynamically-add-and-remove-input-jquery/69377411#69377411)

In my example, I was building a form that would allow users to add multiple input names if they had more than one dog.

```
    var counter = 0
    jQuery(function () {
      $(".newDog").click(function(){
        counter ++;
        if (counter < 4) {
          var elem = $("<input/>",{
            type: "text",
            name: `dogname${counter}`
        });
        } else {
          alert("Max Dog 4")
        }
        
        var removeLink = $("<span/>").html("X").click(function(){
            $(elem).remove();
            $(this).remove();
            counter --;
        });
        
        $(".dogname-inputs").append(elem).append(removeLink);
    });
    })
```